# Wifi connection randomly got disconnected and freeze entire computer in ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS lenovo ideapad 310 i5 7th gen

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo

I'm a newbie in Ubuntu and Ask Ubuntu.

I've installed **Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS** in my **Lenovo ideapad 310** (core i5, 7th generation).

Everything looks fine except WiFi. **WiFi gets connected and I can use it. But after some time it gets disconnected and on that time my entire screen freezes. After some time WiFi gets reconnected and everything looks fine again.**

Above situation happens randomly. For your convenience, I'm giving you the information based on the accepted answer of the question: [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205)

- [`My wireless info in Pastebin`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25697411/)

Moreover, information based on [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into/61547#61547)

- [the output of `sudo lshw -class network`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25697456/)
- [the output of `lsusb`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25697463/)
- [the output of `lspci`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25697519/)
- [the output of `rfkill list all`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25697545/)
- [the output of `dmesg | grep -i firmware`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25697564/)

Any help on that issue will be highly appreciated.